# Seeking DOS 6.22 archiver which packs and unpacks in modern 7zip or zip formats

Tags: archiving, dos

OS: DOS 6.22

Memory manager: EMM386.EXE is not installed.

I'm searching for archiver (command line) which can:

- create zip or 7z archive, which can be opened on Windows 10 with latest 7zip archiver.
- unpack modern zip, 7z, rar, arj formats on DOS 6.22 to FAT16 partition.
- while packing, it shouldn't run out of memory and hang as 7za 4.65 does.
- it should support DOS 6.22 on Pentium4 1600 mhz computer with 128 Mb RAM without crashes.
- I should be able to pack the whole FAT16 drive C (I mean files and folders recursively) to drive D with zip or 7z filetype.

I've tried:

- 7za 4.65 with different compression formats and modes and it crashes or throws different errors.
- rar32 (unknown version) causes the page fault.
- 7za 16.02 doesn't compress and throws 'no more files' error
- 7za 4.42 throws SIGSEGV

Comment: This thing called "[7zdec](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/pkg-html/7zdec.html)" is supposed to run on DOS. Possibly, though "[FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/software/)" isn't DOS 6.22 compatible? Worth a look?

Comment: This is a decompressor. I need compressor-decompressor.

Comment: Look for old PKZIP packages; I don't recall version numbers that were DOS-compatible, but the older, the more likely to be useful to you. Note that you may have to break up large archives into floppy-sized volumes with older versions.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin but it won't unpack modern zip, 7z, rar

Comment: OK, I missed the "open current-version archives" requirement. I don't think you're going to be able to get that _and_ DOS 6.22 compatibility; DOS usage today is, for the most part, either legacy or embedded, and neither of those usages is conducive to development of modern general-purpose compatibility.